# How to use Ruby's send method without receiver?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to convert user input à la "6 months" into a Ruby method à la `6.months`.

How can this be done?

I keep getting an `undefined method 6.months` error in line 10.

Thanks for any help.

```
class Coupon < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.duration_options
    ["3 years", "2 years", "1 year", "6 months", "3 months", "1 month"]
  end

  def end_at
    if Coupon.duration_options.include?(duration)
      method = duration.sub!(' ', '.')
      time = Time.zone.now + send(method)
    end
    time
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `send` is on the object itself, in this case it's `self.send(method)`

You could do like this

```
if Coupon.duration_options.include?(duration)
  off_set = duration.split(" ")
  time = Time.zone.now + off_set.first.to_i.send(off_set.last.to_sym)
end
time
```